Why is $\varphi$ differentiable?
In the proof of a lemma (called the fundamental integral equation for the non-ruin probability) in the book Non-Life Insurance Mathematics by Thomas Mikosch (page 164) we get to the following expression (not exactly, but the constants aren't relevant to the question):
\begin{align*}
 \varphi(u) \,=\, e^u\!\int_{u}^{\infty}\!e^{-z}g(z)\,\text{d}z,  
\end{align*}
where
$$
g(z) \,= \int_{0}^{z}\!\varphi(z - x)\,\text{d}F_X(x).
$$
The expression is followed by a statement that the function $\varphi$ is differentiable with respect to $u$. Why is that so? I'm a bit rusty on analysis, but how can we differentiate an improper integral? The relevant information is also that $\varphi: (0, \infty)\to[0,1]$ is a bounded function, and the expression in $g(z)$ is integrated with respect to a distribution function measure of some random variable $X$ that has a density.

Are the "$\varphi(u)$" and "$\varphi(z-x)$" the same "$\varphi$"?

Yes, they are the same function, but I seem to have forgot a detail. I'll fix it now

Use the product rule and fundamental theorem of calculus. Also the integral is not improper.

We are integrating over a set that has infinite measure? How is the integral not improper?

The fact that the integral runs to $z=+\infty$ does not matter as long as the function under the integral sign is continuous and absolutely integrable, because in that case the main theorem of integral calculus guarantees that the integral is differentiable with derivative $-e^{-u}g(u).$ Differentiability of $\varphi$ is then an easy consequence.
If the function under the integral sign is only absolutely integrable but not necessarily continuous, there is still an analog of the main theorem whereby the integral as a function of $u$ is differentiable at almost every $u$ in the sense that the set of $u$ where it is not, has measure zero.
The second integral formula guarantees that $|g(z)|\le\|\varphi\|_\infty$ and  therefore the function under the first integral is absolutely integrable.

$\varphi(u)$ is defined as $P\left(\sup_{n\geq1}S_n\leq u\right)$ where $S_n$ is a discrete random walk along the reals. $S_n$ has a density so I believe that implies that $\varphi$ is continuous.

That's reassuring. The fact that $X$ has a density remains important if we like $g$ to be continuous.
